# Applying updates to a ResultSet with UCanAccess only updates the first row

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to update multiple rows i a Microsoft access database using ucanaccess in Java. Problem is that after updating the first row nothing else happens as if cursor were closed. Here is my code:

```
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+ filepath);
    String qry = "SELECT * FROM Elenco_Aziende";

    Statement stmtautisti = on.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);

    String qryautisti = "SELECT * FROM Elenco_Autisti";
    ResultSet rsautisti = stmtautisti.executeQuery(qryautisti);

    while (rsautisti.next()) {
    rsautisti.updateString("Problemi", "Nessuno");
    rsautisti.updateRow();
    }
```

after executing just the first row is updated...is this a known bug with ucanaccess or something else?

Comment: Not MS Access specialist, but in general - wouldn't it be easier, instead of updating each record separately, just run `UPDATE Elenco_Aziende SET Problemi='Nessuno'` and let DB handle it for you?

Comment: @Sva.Mu True, although sometimes [mcve] code does trivial or "not really applicable to the real world" things just to illustrate the point.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I don't have to update "all" rows, but I must loop on the rows and for each row, based on some extra condition I decide to update them or not. While troubleshooting on the problem I got that even a simple loop like the one I described: while (rsautisti.next()) {
    rsautisti.updateString("Problemi", "Nessuno");
    rsautisti.updateRow();
    } just updates first record. Besides if try the solution Sva.Mu propose that is simpler than my scenario I got error "UCAExc:::3.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: PROBLEMI"...so really confused now please help me

Comment: In the Sva.Mu sql statement the table name is wrong (whereas both the sql and the suggestion are formally correct). It should be: UPDATE Elenco_Autisti SET Problemi='Nessuno' and not UPDATE Elenco_Aziende SET Problemi='Nessuno'. I can't reproduce your issue: in a very similar case I can update each result set row. I'll try again and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

This issue appears to be related to the behaviour of HSQLDB (which UCanAccess uses "under the hood"). According to the [HSQLDB documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_jdbc_autocommit)

> In autocommit mode, all ResultSet objects are read-only and holdable.

So, in order to be able to update the ResultSet we need to `con.setAutoCommit(false)` before opening it, and then do a `con.commit()` to write the changes back to the database.

For more discussion regarding this issue see [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/9489ecce/) at the UCanAccess forum.

Comment: Hello guys thanks I found for now a workaround...see it at link https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/9489ecce/

Comment: Accordingly with the Gord's answer, you don't need any workaround but just  put a con.setAutoCommit(false) before executing the query and a con.commit() after the loop.